# Adding timestamps to supervisord logs

Tags: logging, supervisord, timestamp

Is it possible to let supervisord add timestamps to the outputs in `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile`? I couldn't find it anything about that in the [documentation](http://supervisord.org/logging.html#child-process-logs).

Comment: Send the output to the syslog and let it take care of this?

Comment: There are a lot of messages from the child process and for the purpose of traceability I need them without the syslog clutter.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02. If you are running in Docker, then let the docker container capture stdin/stdout and capture timestamps that way. If not, send output to syslog and let either systemd or rsyslog append their timetstamps. Unless your system is heavily loaded (and rsyslog/systemd cannot keep up), this should get you what you need.

See [this answer](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) for docker.

See [the official documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html) for rsyslogd and search for "precision". For some vendors (RedHat, Ubuntu) this may already be enabled by default.

See [this nice tutorial](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/using-journalctl/) on using journalctl with systemd.

Comment: I think the lack of support for timestamps and journal are a dealbreaker for a lot of people including me.  Systemd does all that out of the box.  The only downside of using systemd is that you need to code in `sd_notify` heartbeat on the client-side to use the watchdog feature.